# How to sort the multidimensional array obtained as a result in PHP

Tags: php

From query I got a multidimensional array. Later I need to sort this array to provide a response to the user. I want to sort the array based on position. I'm not able to do it using a foreach / for loop.

Code:

```php
$getImages = $this->event_model->getpromotinaldataAll();
    $getOffers = $this->event_model->getAllOffersdata();

    foreach($getImages as $row) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp['id'] = $row->pid;
        $tmp['name'] = $row->partnername;
        $tmp['latitude'] = $row->latitude;
        $tmp['longitude'] = $row->longitude;
        $tmp['image_url'] = $url.$row->image;
        //$tmp['date'] = $row->created_at;
        $tmp['type'] = $row->type;
        $tmp['position'] = $row->position;
        $tmp['objectId'] = $row->couponId;
        $tmp['actionTitle'] = $row->actionTitle;
        array_push($response, $tmp);
    }

    foreach($getOffers as $row) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp['id'] = $row->id;
        $tmp['name'] = $row->name;
        $tmp['latitude'] = "";
        $tmp['longitude'] = "";
        $tmp['image_url'] = $url.$row->image;
        //$tmp['date'] = $row->date;
        $tmp['type'] = $row->type;
        $tmp['position'] = $row->position;
        $tmp['objectId'] = $row->eventId;
        $tmp['actionTitle'] = $row->actionTitle;
        array_push($response, $tmp);
    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Saltocean
            [latitude] => 12.913510
            [longitude] => 77.487395
            [image_url] => 
            [type] => 1
            [position] => 2
            [objectId] => 3
            [actionTitle] => Create Invite
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => saurabh hotel
            [latitude] => 28.6466759
            [longitude] => 76.8123909
            [image_url] => 
            [type] => 1
            [position] => 4
            [objectId] => 4
            [actionTitle] => Create Invite
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => trial
            [latitude] => 
            [longitude] => 
            [image_url] => 
            [type] => 2
            [position] => 2
            [objectId] => 4
            [actionTitle] => Invite Me
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => trial
            [latitude] => 
            [longitude] => 
            [image_url] => 
            [type] => 2
            [position] => 1
            [objectId] => 4
            [actionTitle] => Invite Me
        )
)
```

Comment: *"From query I got a multidimensional array."* -- the best option is to use `SORT BY` in SQL and get the results already sorted. If this is not possible then use [`array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"From query I got a multidimensional array."* -- the best option is to use `SORT BY` in SQL and get the results already sorted.

If this is not possible then use [`array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#refsect1-function.array-multisort-examples). Assuming your array is stored in the variable `$data`, this is how you can sort it by the values of `position`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'position'), SORT_ASC, $data);
```

For more examples and explanation how this works, read the [documentation of `array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

Comment: thank you..it works as i expected.

Comment: $pos = array();
                    foreach ($response as $key => $row)
                    {
                        $pos[$key] = $row['position'];
                    }
                    array_multisort($pos, SORT_ASC, $response);

Comment: even this code worked well

Comment: `array_column()` does the `foreach` for you and it works faster. If `array_column()` does not exist on your PHP version (it has been introduced in PHP 5.5) then upgrade to PHP 7.2. Older versions are [outdated and not maintained any more](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<?php

$data = array_column($response, 'position');

// ascending order
ksort($data);

// descending order
krsort($data);

// if you want to reset the keys of the array
array_values($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

one method :

```
array_multisort(array_column($response, 'position'), SORT_ASC, $response);
```

second method:

```
$pos = array();
                    foreach ($response as $key => $row)
                    {
                        $pos[$key] = $row['position'];
                    }
                    array_multisort($pos, SORT_ASC, $response);
```

Comment: I thought that you not able to do it using a foreach like you said in the question, so i used `array_column` in my answer.